# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'TSCLIB': The specified module could not be found

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I am trying to print TSC-244 Pro Bar Code Label Printer from GWT Web Application. They give tsclib.dll. Thus why I use jna.jar and copy tsclib.dll file to C:\Windows and [my_project_dir]\war\WEB-INF\lib. Its work but when I deploy to apache tomcat. It doesn't work and I got following error. Please give me solution. Thank.

SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract boolean com.mbc.client.Controller.print(java.lang.String,java.util.ArrayList) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'TSCLIB': The specified module could not be found.

```
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'TSCLIB': The specified module could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:164)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:237)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:375)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:360)
at com.mbc.server.impls.TscLibDll.<clinit>(TscLibDll.java:8)
at com.mbc.server.util.BarCode.openport(BarCode.java:73)
at com.mbc.server.util.Printer.openBarCodePrinter(Printer.java:67)
at com.mbc.server.util.Printer.printtsc(Printer.java:97)
at com.mbc.server.util.Printer.print(Printer.java:35)
at com.mbc.server.ControllerServlet.print(ControllerServlet.java:1390)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I can't find the TSCLIB.dll because I just downloaded dll file for `32 bit`. My apache tomcat program is located in `64 bit`. Thus why Unable to load library 'TSCLIB'. Now I just downloaded `64 bit` dll file and copied to `C:\Windows\sysWOW64\`. It's work! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `TscLib.DLL` to your [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/relnotes-136027.html#tools) for the native code in `com.mbc.server.impls.TscLibDll` to work.

Comment: @ChesterDenn There's no code, it's an environment variable. `set "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<SOME_PATH>"` where `<SOME_PATH>` contains `TscLib.DLL`

Comment: Then you haven't set it correctly. Note this is a native library we are talking about (not a Java class).

Comment: Did you mean to set in System Variable, didn't you? I set Variable name: LD_LIBRARY_PATH and Variable value: %SystemRoot%\TSCLIB.dll. Wrong?

Comment: Try "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%SystemRoot%" assuming "TSCLIB.dll" is actually in `SystemRoot`. If it isn't working and you still get the above exception, then you haven't found the correct "TSCLIB.dll"